# Problema ao enviar notification com parametros

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Estou com problemas em um app android, ao tentar enviar uma notification tudo ocorre 100% até chegar na abertura da activity da notification.

Essa activity chamada precisa de um parametro "store" e não estou conseguindo enviar ele via notification.

Vejam os fontes abaixo:

```
private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.header_logo,"New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NewReviewActivity.this,ReviewActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("store",String.valueOf(store.getStore_id()));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NewReviewActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


    notification.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(NewReviewActivity.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
}
```

E meu logcat:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projects.storefinder/com.projects.activities.ReviewActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.models.Store
```

Está claro que o problema é que o parâmetro não está sendo devidamente passado.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Pode mostrar como você tenta pegar o parametro? Onde ocorre o erro? Valeu!

Comment: Claro Thiago,

Segue:
store = (Store) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("store");

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está enviando uma String e espera receber um objeto do tipo Store.
O que você envia como String é o ID da Store. Provavelmente você consegue recuperar essa Store a partir do ID enviado.
Tente mudar a linha que dá erro para:

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("store");
```

Comment: Funcionou, era isso mesmo Diego! Valeu